# How to use "flow_from_directory" of Multi path&Multi classes

Tags: python, keras

I modified it from https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/data.py#L48

I concatenate 6 GLCM images and append 7 classes concatenated image to perform a UNet classification task.

In Generator,#code are concatenate & append code.

But in training, system only read class1 image mask then in this for loop forever

```
for six_img, six_mask in zip(img_zip,mask_zip):
```

I think img_zip & mask_zip are from zip(*img_append) zip(*mask_append) then ther are from generator, but I

dont know how to let image_generator & mask_generator read multi path at same time, I tried input

list[paths] but image_generator cant not accept list

```
folders = [
    'classes1/glcm1', #7 classes, 42 paths
    'classes1/glcm2',
    'classes1/glcm3',
    'classes1/glcm4',
    'classes1/glcm5', 
    'classes1/glcm6',
    'classes2/glcm1',
        …
    'classes7/glcm6',
]
```

```
def Generator(folders,.....)
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    for paths in folders:
        image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            paths,...)
        mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            paths,...)

    #    img_append.append(image_generator)
    #    mask_append.append(mask_generator)
    #    count += 1
    #    if count %6 == 0:
    #        img_zip = zip(*img_append)
    #        mask_zip = zip(*mask_append)
    #        for six_img, six_mask in zip(img_zip,mask_zip):
    #            img_concatenate = np.concatenate(six_img, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 8)
    #            mask_concatenate = np.concatenate(six_mask, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 6)
    #            img_concatenate_append.append(img_concatenate)
    #            mask_concatenate_append.append(mask_concatenate)  
    #        img_append = []
    #        mask_append = []
    for (img, mask) in zip(img_concatenate_append, mask_concatenate_append):
        yield (img,mask)
```